# How to run a program with administrator privileges on user login under Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows, administrator, scheduled-tasks, temperature, monitoring

I would  like to run a task to monitor CPU temperature while I am logged into my regular working account, which does not have admin privileges.  However, admin privileges are required to read the CPU temperature.
The answers provided [here](https://superuser.com/questions/920697/how-to-run-a-program-with-administrator-privileges-on-user-login-under-windows), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1222529/windows-10-home-edition-scheduled-task-wont-run-with-admin-privileges) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/770420/schedule-a-task-with-admin-privileges-without-a-user-prompt-in-windows-7) don't work for me under Windows 10 Pro x64 20H2.  I have tried many different options, including batch scripts, VBS scripts and scheduled tasks with all of the available compatibility options:

- Vista (default)
- Windows 7
- Windows 10

Most of the posts I have found recommend scheduled tasks. However, if I choose "Run whether user is logged in or not", the process starts, but no UI is visible.
If I choose "Run only when user is logged on", the task logs the following error:

```
Event ID:      332
Task Category: Launch condition not met, user not logged-on
```

I have tried using the LOCAL SERVICE account, the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account, a local admin account and a domain admin account to run the scheduled task, all without success.  The LOCAL SERVICE account and the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account both enforce "Run whether user is logged in or not", so the process starts but doesn't display a UI.
I have tried using both OpenHardwareMonitor and Core Temp as monitor programs, but they both behave the same.
How can I monitor my CPU temperature in my regular working account without having to manually start the monitor program and acknowledge the UAC prompt each time I log in?

Comment: Check in the Task Scheduler screen where you set "Run whether user is logged in ..."  and also set (enable) "Run with Highest Privileges"  . You will need to OK this.  Try with and without  "Hidden" .  See if this starts your CPU monitor.

Comment: You want a scheduled task to run with GUI when no user is logged-on? This is impossible.

Comment: @John, Thanks, but I have tried these options without success.

Comment: @harrymc, I‘m afraid you have misunderstood.  The task should run when I am logged in *as a normal user*.  In order to read CPU temperature, the task needs to run with admin privileges. However, since I am getting the error, „user not logged-on“, the setting „Run whether user is logged in or not“ seems to apply specifically to the user specified in the task, not to just any user.

Comment: I think that's the problem: The option of "Run whether user is logged in or not" means non-interactive.

Comment: Mistake in my comment above: I meant to say that „Run only when user is logged on“ applies specifically to the user specified in the task, not to any user.